# Beamer overlays - how to make things appear in different places?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

So I just started using beamer and got introduced to the `\pause` command. But I want things to show up at different places on the screen, not necessarily from top to bottom. How to do that?

Specifically, what I have is a `tikzpicture` and then some text below, for example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
<Draw a circle>
<Draw a rectangle>
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{itemize}
\item Adding a circle
\item Adding a rectangle
\end{itemize}
```

I want to make the beamer frame such that when I press enter the text "adding a circle" shows up at the same time as the circle shows up in the `tikzpicture`, and then I press enter again and "adding a rectangle" shows up at the same time as the rectangle shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Please compile the following and see which of these two frames you are looking for. Please let me know if you want other effects.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

% Entities replace each other in vertical space.
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    \begin{center}
      <Draw a circle>
    \end{center}

    \onslide<2>
    \begin{center}
      <Draw a rectangle>      
    \end{center}
  \end{overprint}

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Adding a circle
    \end{itemize}

    \onslide<2>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Adding a rectangle
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

% Entities appear below each other in vertical space, but do not appear together
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    \begin{center}
      <Draw a circle>
    \end{center}

    \onslide<2>
    \begin{center}
      <Draw a rectangle>      
    \end{center}
  \end{overprint}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1> Adding a circle
  \item<2> Adding a rectangle
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you provide multiple ideas, also `\only<x>` and `\visible<x>` would be great as a comparison.

Comment: @Ronny I could provide other examples/ideas, but the original questioner was not very clear about what he was asking for. So, I decided to provide a basic few.

Comment: okay, then maybe these commands might inspire the OP to find, what fits best to his needs :)